# How to make tsavedialog to remember last used folder?

Tags: delphi

I want my SaveDialog to remember last used folder. I am talking about remembering last folder in the current running session. I am already saving the path to a INI file for 'between-session'.

When i call SaveDialog.Execute, the path is reset to InitialDir.

Comment: when SaveDialog is executed, set InitialDir to ExtractFilePath(SaveDialog1.FileName).  If you want your program to remember every time it is started, then you need to have a mechanism to remember, such as using the registry or a confif file in %APPDATA%

Comment: It's up to you to implement this

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-Thanks david. I though that TSaveDialog already has something like this implemented and I just need to turn it on.

Comment: @Altar: The OS does keep track of the last folder used on a per-app basis. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839.aspx) for the `OPENFILENAME::lpstrInitialDir` field explains the algorithm used to determine when the stored folder is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the initialDir to the new Directory,

```
      if  (SaveDialog1.Execute) then
      begin
         SaveDialog1.InitialDir := ExtractFilePath(SaveDialog1.FileName);
         //Save your file
      end;
```

If you want your program to remember even after it is closed down, then save the new directory to the registry, on upon open it again, read it, or maybe use a configuration file saved in your program's %APPDATA% directory.

Comment: Set it when the program starts (in FormCreate or FormShow), then everytime the SaveDialog Executes.  You can't set it before it executes with the NEW directory, because SaveDialog1.FileName has not been set until AFTER it is executed.

Comment: You question was specifically how to set initial directory to the last selected directory.  Not how to set it on initialization.  Like I mentioned in my comment, set it to a known good directory (such as my Documents) in FormCreate, or FormShow.  Using SaveDialog1.FileName before SaveDialog1.Execute is not what you want...

Comment: You don't need parentheses around boolean function call, BTW.